# How can I speed up this function in Python?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to figure out a way to speed up this function. I am trying to do all pairwise comparisons between the rows and columns of a dataframe (pairwise_df) and store the result. The comparison requires two numpy arrays of continuous values taken from another dataframe (df).

```
pairwise_df = pd.DataFrame(index = ['insert1', 'insert2', 'insert3'], columns = ['insert1', 'insert2', 'insert3'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
                     [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3]], index = ['insert1', 'insert2', 'insert3'], columns = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

```
for row in list(pairwise_df.index.values):
    for col in list(pairwise_df):
        
        pairwise_df.at[row, col] = cosine_sim(np.array(df.loc[row]), np.array(df.loc[col]))
```

This works, but takes about 18mins to run on a 2000 x 2000 dataframe, and i'm sure there are ways to speed this up, but my programming experience is minimal.

The cosine_sim function is here, but the function used will vary so it doesn't matter too much:

```
def cosine_sim(x, y):

    dot = np.dot(x, y)
    norma = np.linalg.norm(x)
    normb = np.linalg.norm(y)
    cos = dot / (norma * normb)
    return cos
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your post with a sample, please?

Comment: @Corralien does my edit help?

Comment: Yes. It's clear now of what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid loops to compute cosine similarity by creating the array of all combinations using `np.tile` and `np.reshape`. The trick here is to use `np.einsum` to replace the dot product.

```
m = df.values
x = np.tile(m, m.shape[0]).reshape(-1, m.shape[1])
y = np.tile(m.T, m.shape[0]).T
c = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', x, y) / (np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1) * np.linalg.norm(y, axis=1))
```

```
>>> c.reshape(-1, m.shape[0])
array([[1.        , 0.57142857, 0.75283826],
       [0.57142857, 1.        , 0.74102903],
       [0.75283826, 0.74102903, 1.        ]])
```

Comment: This was incredibly fast (7 seconds).

However, I needed to change y = np.tile(m.T, 3).T to y = np.tile(m.T, m.shape[0]).T since my real dataset has more than 3 columns.

Also, how would I implement this if I wanted to calculate something other than cosine similarity?

Comment: I am accepting your answer since it solves my specific problem, though i'm not sure if this is generalizable to other methods outside of cosine similarity, any insight would be hepful!